# Can not delete cache key in SWR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, swr

I am trying to delete SWR cache by key like

```
const { cache } = useSWRConfig()
...
useEffect(() => {
   return () => cache.delete('/api/history')
}
```

but i am still getting the cached response and request is not sent. (Revalidation is not an option here). I made sure delete method is called on unmount

Comment: What does your `useSWR` call look like? Have you looked at what is returned by `cache.keys()` (can just `console.log` it) and see if its what you expect? SWR will run the key through one of its internal functions called `serialize` (which is available as `import { serialize } from 'swr/_internal';`, but could cause issues with future changes to SWR as it is not intended for external use) and this function creates what is used as the actual key based on the intended key you provide (this should be the exact string if you only provided a string). Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: This is the [serialize](https://github.com/vercel/swr/blob/main/_internal/src/utils/serialize.ts) function. The first item in the tuple will be the calculated key that it will use to store the data in cache, the second item is the provided key (if you use a complex key this will most likely be another tuple).

Comment: there is nothing complicated in hook call. and i am using plain string as a key
also cache.keys() returns empty iterator

Comment: @JacobSmit not sure if you saw my comment

Comment: hmm, Have you using an `SWRConfig` component? Is one of the hooks inside and the other outside this component?

Comment: @JacobSmit what do you mean ? are you talking about custom hooks ?

Comment: yeah figured out that swr caches response from custom hook but does not let delete it or access it, gotta find a workaround